# L298 Motor Driver not showing Red light when connecting power supply

Tags: motor

I recently bought an L298 motor driver module for controlling 2 motors(5v each).

When i connect the power supply(which is a normal RC car battery holder(3)) the red light doesn't light up.

Instead if i connect the +ve to the 5v on the motor driver, the red light is glowing, but the motors don't work.

Comment: you accepted an answer that is not quite correct ... the reason that motors do not run is that the L298 is technology from last century and is very inefficient ... your power supply needs to be a bit higher than 7 V if your motor requires 5 V ... the L298 uses up a couple of Volts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do math on the power consumption as arduino uno takes takes 5 V 500 mA at least for it to work. That is why it can be powered by USB cables too.
Now if you try calculating power consumption on the motors you would understand that the power you are giving is nowhere enough for the arrangement to work or you could have been able to run the motors without the motor driver.
Try upgrading the power you are giving.

Comment: Thanks. I tweaked up the power and now its working fine.

Comment: @RiteshSharma  your answer provides incorrect information ... Arduino Uno requires a lot less current than 500 mA to operate ... please research the correct value and update your answer .... you also used incorrect units of measure, which I edited

Comment: I would definitely do the research work on that @jsotola